# MYSQL query - getting totals by month

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a6b1

The scheme is given above.. all I want to do is get the results as the total of sales/month... the user will enter a start date and end date and I can generate (in PHP) all the month and years for those dates. For example, if I want to know the total number of "sales" for 12 months, I know I can run 12 individual queries with start and end dates, but I want to run only one query where the result will look like:

```
Month     numofsale
January - 2  
Feb-1
March - 23
Apr - 10
```

and so on...

or just a list of sales without the months, I can then pair it to the array of months generated in the PHP ...any ideas...

Edit/schema and data pasted from sqlfiddle.com:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lead_activity2` (
  `lead_activity_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sp_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `act_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `act_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`lead_activity_id`),
  KEY `act_date` (`act_date`),
  KEY `act_name` (`act_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1  ;

INSERT INTO `lead_activity2` (`lead_activity_id`, `sp_id`, `act_date`, `act_name`) VALUES
(1, 5, '2012-10-16 16:05:29', 'sale'),
(2, 5, '2012-10-16 16:05:29', 'search'),
(3, 5, '2012-10-16 16:05:29', 'sale'),
(4, 5, '2012-10-17 16:05:29', 'DNC'),
(5, 5, '2012-10-17 16:05:29', 'sale'),
(6, 5, '2012-09-16 16:05:30', 'SCB'),
(7, 5, '2012-09-16 16:05:30', 'sale'),
(8, 5, '2012-08-16 16:05:30', 'sale'),
(9, 5,'2012-08-16 16:05:30', 'sale'),
(10, 5, '2012-07-16 16:05:30', 'sale');
```

Comment: I see create tables and insert dummy data code, what have you tried for the 'select' statement?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, "%m-%Y") AS Month, SUM(numofsale)
FROM <table_name>
WHERE <where-cond>
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, "%m-%Y")
```

Check following in your fiddle demo it works for me (remove `where` clause for testing)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(act_date, "%m-%Y") AS Month, COUNT(*)
FROM lead_activity2
WHERE <where-cond-here> AND act_name='sale'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(act_date, "%m-%Y")
```

It returns following result

```
MONTH   COUNT(*)
07-2012 1
08-2012 2
09-2012 1
10-2012 3
```

Comment: You can use `DATE_FORMAT(act_date, "%M-%Y")` for `July-2012` Ref:- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: It will not display in the result the months where sales number is zero

Comment: why not `GROUP BY Month`?

Comment: This will display the total sales by month in all year, however if anyone need to display it in a specific year, just add `YEAR(act_date) = 2012` in the `<where-cond-here>`

Answer (score 2):

You can try query as given below

```
select  SUM(`SP_ID`) AS `Total` , DATE_FORMAT(act_date, "%M") AS Month, Month(`ACT_DATE`) AS `Month_number` from `lead_activity2`  WHERE `ACT_DATE` BETWEEN '2012-05-01' AND '2012-12-17' group by Month(`ACT_DATE`)
```

Here `2012-05-01` and `2012-12-17` are date input from form. and It will be return you the sum of sales for particular month if exist in database.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this query -

```
SELECT
  MONTH(act_date) month, COUNT(*)
FROM
  lead_activity2
WHERE
  YEAR(act_date) = 2012 AND act_name = 'sale'
GROUP BY
  month
```

Check WHERE condition if it is OK for you - `act_name = 'sale'`.

If you want to output month names, then use **MONTHNAME()** function instead of **MONTH()**.

Comment: well i tired this SELECT 
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM act_date) as month, 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM act_date) as year, 
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    lead_activity2
WHERE
    act_name="sale"
GROUP BY 
    month, 
    year
ORDER BY 
    year DESC, 
    month DESC

Comment: dev your query works....but i guess the solution i posted was a more complete one as it seems to have been doing the sorting and stuff..... will select yours

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT YEAR(act_date), MONTH(act_date), COUNT(*)

FROM lead_activity2

GROUP BY YEAR(act_date), MONTH(act_date)
```

For getting data by month or any other data based on column you have to add GROUP BY.

You can add many columns or calculated values to GROUP BY.

I assume that "num of sales" means count of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you might want the month names as Jan, Feb, Mar .... Dec possibly for a Chart like[FusionChart](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, "%M") AS Month, SUM(numofsale)
FROM <Table_name>
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, "%M")
```

Results would look like this on table

```
MONTH   COUNT(*)
Jul       1
Aug       2
SEP       1
OCT       3
```